# `deriving (Data)` vs `deriving (Generic)`

Tags: haskell, ghc

What's the difference between these two in GHC. They seem similar in intended purpose but `deriving (Data)` has been around for a while yet `deriving (Generic)` has only been added to GHC recently.

Is `deriving (Generic)` basically an "upgrade" to `deriving (Data)` or do the two classes have different purposes?

Comment: These are just type classes - you can look at the methods and infer their uses.  In short, `Data`, provides flexible methods for traversing data structures while `Generic` provides a method to translate user defined structures to and from a single "sum of products" form; it is then up to the user to define how to traverse this sum of products AST.

Comment: You may be interested in some papers: http://dreixel.net/research/pdf/gdmh.pdf (introduction of Generic), http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Research_papers/Generics (some of the comparisons in the Overview, and Scrap Your Boilerplate for info on `Data.Data`).  These are generally pretty readable.

Answer (score 3):

I almost hesitate to answer this question, because I only marginally understand it myself, but I did spend a couple of days looking at this myself about a year ago, and this is my current understanding....

Both classes are used for introspection....  Using them, you can get access to the Haskell code parsetrees (of the Haskell program itself).

Philosophically, the way that they do this differs, however.

1. deriving (Data) creates data objects, which represent the parsed tree of objects that can be manipulated at runtime.
2. deriving (Generic) creates new Types corresponding to each parsetree, which often can be manipulated at compile time (leaving less work to be done at runtime).

From my limited usage, "deriving (Data)" was much more straightforward to use, but of course wasn't as sleek at runtime (....for me this was negligable).

Although "deriving (Generic)" was theoretically faster, it was trickier to program, and involved creating classes that could manipulate groups of Types (ie- related parsetrees).  It also may push you into using cutting edge GHC extensions.

My opinion- "deriving (Generic)" is the "right" way to do things, but would take longer to master.

Template Haskell is another way to access Haskell parsetrees, although it works 100% at compiletime, and has tools to let you *create* and *insert* parse tree data into the code (ie- code that generates code, like a Lisp macro).

Again, let me stress that this is all based on a couple of days of research, so if I have mangled this too badly, someone let me know (I myself would like to firm up my understanding).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've upvoted but I'll leave the question open incase there are other insights.

Comment: deriving `Data` creates `Data` dictionaries (type class instances), which provide higher-order functions that work over the tree of objects (in particular, `gfoldl`).  Also, IMHO `Generic` is much simpler to use than `Data`, and leads to much simpler code.

Comment: @JohnL Let's not forget to mention the exponential blow-up in boilerplate Generic causes over Data (ex: traversals using Generic classes vs `everything` et al from SYB)!